# How can I appropriately include external resources with cxfreeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm trying to use [cxfreeze](https://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils) to build my Python scripts into an `.exe` file.  However my scripts use some external data files which aren't being packaged into the `libary.zip` file created.

For example, my scripts are located in `src/`, and the external data is located in `src/data/`.  I've specified the `include_files` property in the `build_exe_options`, but this only *copies* the directory and files into the built directory; it doesn't add them to `library.zip`, which is where the scripts end up looking for the files.

Even if I go in to the created `library.zip` and manually add the `data` directory, I receive the same error.  Any idea how to get `cxfreeze` to package these external resources appropriately?

**setup.py**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"includes" : ["re"], "include_files" : ["data/table_1.txt", "data/table_2.txt"]}

setup(name = "My Script",
      version = "0.8",
      description = "My Script",
      options = { "build_exe" : build_exe_options },
      executables = [Executable("my_script.py")])
```

**fileutil.py** (where it tries to read the resource files)

```
def read_file(filename):
    path, fl = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(path, filename)
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in file]
        return [line for line in lines if len(line) == 0 or line[0] != "#"]
```

... called with ...

```
read_file("data/table_1.txt")
```

**Error Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 2
7, in <module> exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "my_script.py", line 94, in <module>
  File "my_script.py", line 68, in run
  File "C:\workspaces\py\test_script\src\tables.py", line 12, in load_data
    raw_gems = read_file("data/table_1.txt")
  File "C:\workspaces\py\test_script\src\fileutil.py", line 8, in read_file
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'C:\\workspaces\\py\\test_script\\src\\build\\exe.win32-3.3\\library.zip\\data/table_1.txt'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following structure worked for me:

```
|-main.py
|-src
 |-utils.py (containing get_base_dir())
|-data
```

then refer to your data always relative to the location of main.py that you receive through the following function within the src directory:

```
import os, sys, inspect
def get_base_dir():
   if getattr(sys,"frozen",False):
       # If this is running in the context of a frozen (executable) file, 
       # we return the path of the main application executable
       return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.executable))
   else:
       # If we are running in script or debug mode, we need 
       # to inspect the currently executing frame. This enable us to always
       # derive the directory of main.py no matter from where this function
       # is being called
       thisdir = os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))
       return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(thisdir, os.pardir))
```

If you include the data according to the cx_Freeze documentation, it will be in the same directory as the `.exe`file (i.e. not in the zipfile), which will work with this solution.

Comment: Here's the relevant bit of the docs: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files